# How to reference the name of a val in a Object class in scaladoc?

Tags: scala, scaladoc

Is there a way that I can reference the name of a val in a Object class using scaladoc, similar to

```
{@value #STATIC_FIELD}
```

in javadoc.

Comment: Hmm. `@value` references the value of the constant in Javadoc. Did you mean `@link`?

Comment: Is this not supported still?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I link variables inside another object in scaladocs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64584331/how-do-i-link-variables-inside-another-object-in-scaladocs)

Answer (score 1):

you can do it two ways:

```
package your.package_path


object SomeObject extends App {

  val someList: List[Int] = List.empty[Int]

  /**
   * @see [[your.package_path.SomeObject#someList]]
   * @see [[someList]]
   * ...
   */
  def bar(): String = ???
}
```