# How do I link variables inside another object in scaladocs?

Tags: scala, sbt, scaladoc

To link another class, I can use `[[package.Classname]]`.
Linking functions defined by `def` works as well, but trying to link variables doesn't work.

What I've tried:

```scala
object Foo {

  val BAR = 0
}

object Example {

  /**
  * Does the thing with [[Foo.BAR]]
  */
  def doTheThing(): Unit = {

  }
}
```

I've also tried `[[Foo#BAR]]` (from another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29854895/how-to-reference-the-name-of-a-val-in-a-object-class-in-scaladoc)) instead of `[[Foo.BAR]]`, which fails as well.

What's the proper way to link variables in scaladoc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The right way to go is what you have already tried:

```
/**
* Does the thing with [[Foo.BAR]]
*/
```

Please note that if this is just an example to a more complicated scenario, you need to include the whole package path of `Foo.BAR`. For example, if `Foo` is under:

```
package a.b.c.d
```

Then you need to do:

```
/**
* Does the thing with [[a.b.c.d.Foo.BAR]]
*/
```

You can find in the scaladocs [docs](https://docs.scala-lang.org/style/scaladoc.html):

> Create links to referenced Scala Library classes using the square-bracket syntax, e.g. [[scala.Option]]

For more information you can read [SCALADOC FOR LIBRARY AUTHORS](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/scaladoc/for-library-authors.html)

You can see [here](https://github.com/akka/akka-http/blob/master/akka-http/src/main/scala/akka/http/scaladsl/server/directives/PathDirectives.scala#L221) and example how the `akka` library is using it.